# How do i secure my google tag manager id for my domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have integrated google tag manager with my SPA application (ReactJS)

```
const tagManagerArgs = {
    gtmId: 'GTM-000000'
}
 
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
```

I believe by inspecting the source code anyone can see the gtmId (tag manager ID) and by sending events to our workspace.

Question is how can we restrict this tag ID either to accept requests from a specific domain or encrypting/decrypting so that no one else can use this tag ID.

Comment: I don't think there would be an easy way. All tracking code are exposed to the source. If you want to filter the spam traffic, it will depend on the deep you want to avoid it.  Adding the GTM trigger for only specific domain is a way, but still can fake it on the request.